# What would be my new sample time when applying small-size IFFT to a big-size FFT?

Tags: fft

I have a signal sampled at $Fs$ [Hz], a big size FFT is used to detect some signals, then a small size IFFT is use to transform that portion of the spectrum in the time domain, my question is what would be the new sample time of the IFFT output vector related to the original sample time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your operation will effectively *reduce* the original sampling rate $f_s$ of your signal by $$R = \cfrac{N_{\tt{FFT}}}{N_{\tt{iFFT}}}$$
You would get the same result by **downsampling** your original time-domain signal by that factor, i.e. discarding every $R$ sample. So the new sample time is $$T'_s = R\times T_s $$

#### However,

remember that Nyquist and Shannon tell you that the sampling rate $f_s$ should be at least twice the maximum frequency of the signal you want to sample. If you under-sample the time domain, you get **frequency domain aliasing**.

Well, the reverse happens when you under-sample the frequency domain (doing a *"small size" iFFT*): you get **time domain aliasing**.

The correct way to reduce the sampling rate of a signal is through **decimation**, which is the combination of low-pass filtering + downsampling. The low-pass filter is there precisely to prevent time-domain aliasing artifacts.

To summarize with some pseudocode:

```
x = some signal
Nfft = 1000
Nifft = 500
R = Nfft/Nifft # decimation factor
X = fft(x, Nfft)

# Same as x_downsampled = downsample(x, R), will give time domain aliasing
x_downsampled = real(ifft(X, Nifft)) 

# Correct way, same as x_decimated = decimate(x, R)
x_lpf = filter( x, cutoff = fs/(2*R) )
x_decimated = downsample(x_lpf, R)
```